# Python Creating Classes and using methods

Tags: python

I have two python files. I would like to use variables created in file2.py and print them in file1.py

file1.py

```
print 'Hello world'
print x
```

file2.py

```
x = 2
```

Comment: Maybe you want to reread the chapter about [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) in the Python Tutorial.

Comment: [Live and Let Die](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0oTh1CXRaQ0)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can also access methods from the file you've imported with the import statement.

`import file2 as file
print(file.getValueOfX())`

This works if you have a method in file2 as such:

```
def getValueOfX():
   return x
```

Comment: You used `import` with a capital letter and used a function that was not defined.

Comment: Or you know, `from file2 import x; print(x)`

Comment: Thought I'd give him/her a way to use methods as well since it was written in the title.

Comment: 'Creating classes' was also in the title. I just think OP had no idea what they were doing.

Comment: Actually this is very helpfull as I wanted to work with methods as well

Comment: Just remember that x has to be defined in file2 as well.

Answer (score -2):

You can import the file 2 into the file 1 like this:

```
import file2 as file
print file.x
```

This will help you

Comment: Actually he wants to import file2 in file1, although that is of course a minor detail.